# String data not sending with $.ajax call to php page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

When i pass number with function argument for sending using ajax its working properly but when i pass string such as given below its not receiving in php page.

```js
function loadState(country) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'cardstate.php',
    type: 'get',
    data: { 'country': country },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
    }
  });
}

loadState("Pakistan")
```

```php
// cardstate.php:
$country = $_GET['country'];
echo $country; // not receving string while when i put number its receiving
```

Comment: You're not returning `json` in the response. I'd suggest using `dataType: 'text'` instead - or better yet use `$json_encode()` in your PHP to actually return valid JSON

Comment: Thank your for quick response actually i need the return data in json format to display it in <select> options but my project is that i applying mysql query which do not receiving string data for where clause and i need to pass string data using ajax

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying there, but my point is that you're *not* returning JSON when you should be

Comment: shiw from where are you calling `loadState` function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cardstate.php you should use json_encode

```
// cardstate.php:
$country = $_GET['country'];
echo json_encode($country); // not receving string while when i put number its receiving
```

Comment: Dear but its not working in mysql query when i use like: "select * from table where country = ' ".json_encode($country).'' ' ";

Comment: I haven't seen any mysql query in your php, just an echo.

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadState(country) {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'cardstate.php',
    type: 'GET',
    data: 'country='+country, // <--- changed this as its GET
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data.country); // <---- made this change
    }
  });
}

loadState("Pakistan")
```

And in your PHP, use `json_encode()`

```
// cardstate.php:
$country = $_GET['country'];
echo json_encode(array('country' => $country));
```