# How to send string data with $.ajax call to php page which is used in mysql query

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I use a country drop down to select the country and one states drop down to select the state. What I want to do is when user select the country the states of selected country populate the state drop down.

The problem is when use the country name it doesn't work but if I use a number then it does what it supposed to do. I've listed all my codes below.

**My PHP Code**

```
   <?php
    include('connection/config.php');
    $country = $_GET['country'];
    $qqry = "SELECT state FROM tbl_cc_formate WHERE country LIKE '%$country%'";
    $r = mysql_query($qqry);
    $resultState = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
        $resultState[] = $row[0];
    }
    $encodState = json_encode($resultState);
    echo $encodState;
    ?>
```

**My JQuery Code**

```
 function loadState(country)
        {
            $.ajax({
                    url:'cardstate.php',
                    type: 'get',
                    data:{'country':country},
                    dataType: 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    success: function(data)
                    {
                        $.each(data, function (index, item) {
                        $('#state').append(
                        $('<option></option>').val(item).html(item));
                        });
                    }
                });
        }
```

**My HTML Code**

```
<select id="country" name="country" onchange="loadState(this.value)">
  <option selected value="">- ALL -</option>
  <option value="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
</select>
Select State:                       
<select id="state" name="state">
 <option selected value="">- Select Country -</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Stop using `mysyql_*` it hsa been deprecated switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO` and your code can be compromised using SQL injection so read on _prepares statements_. I don't think  you need use the `LIKE` part as `%$country%` just try removing the `%`.

Comment: since you are using GET method you can append the data to your URL like `cardstate.php?country=england`

Comment: Yes dear thank you for your suggestion its working when i select * data from mysql but when i use where clause with $_POST['country'] its not working.

Comment: did you try it with out the `%` after the `LIKE`. `SELECT state FROM tbl_cc_formate WHERE country LIKE '$country'`

Comment: Yes also not working with string data. How to check the $_POST['country'] in php page for data?

Comment: What is the meaning of *when use the country name it doesn't work but if I use a number then it does what it supposed to do* so in your database if country stored with `id` then obviously it will not get states

Comment: Same question you have asked before https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45856777/string-data-not-sending-with-ajax-call-to-php-page  and also accepted the answer then why again???

Comment: Dear i need to run a query on my mysql database in previous question i think this is about string data problem which i want to test it worked fine on that accepted answer but my problem still not solved by query therefore i again post question with my complete code. But still my problem is unsolved so that i change my code from jquery and json to simple javascript with XMLHttpRequest(). by this method its working fine now.

Answer (score 2):

What error, if any, did you get? Did you console the `data` in the jQuery code? Did you test if php's `echo $encodState` outputs anything? There could be a connection problem, too. So we will need to know what error you are encountering with.

Comment: Dear Lian, i have test my query its work without where clause but when i use where clause with constant value its working fine but when i use $_POST['country'] its not working.

Comment: In this case, you just need to make sure $country is not empty. Try this: `$country = (isset($_GET['country']) AND !empty($_GET['country'])) ? $_GET['country'] : "";` And then, `if(empty($country)) $country = $_POST['country'];`. You might want to sanitize your code, too.